# por que con react el error de cors de djoser y no con curl en la ruta "auth/jwt/create" django

Tags: reactjs, django

tengo un error de cors con django usando una autentucacion con djoser y
djangorestframework, tengo todo de cors bien configurado con django pero el unico error de cors es con la ruta "auth/jwt/create/" y es con react no mas este error.

e probado con curl y todo funciona bien con react y axios no anda, el error no mas esta cuand intento hacer la peticon con post no con options.